# Parent and child class construction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was just checking to see if I was writing my code correctly, for this checking class, and sure enough the checking class was accessing Account correctly. I just had to initialize it correctly.

```
class Checking < Account

    def 
       super
    end

    def balance()
        @balance = principal * (1 + interest_rate / 365) ** 365
    end

end
```

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: `class Checking < Account end` is adequate enough ... your issue is more than likely because rails isn't finding your definition - where did you place it, and where is the error being thrown? I have no idea what you mean by 'because the program is pre written' ... as opposed to being dynamically generated during runtime?

Comment: I could paste the whole code in the link if it will help with any explaination.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary unless it's pertinent to the question.

Comment: Since you are using Rails, this question needs to be more specific about the Rails bits.  Where in the Rails file hierarchy did you put these two classes?  Are they in the same file, or in separate files, and where?  Please also do include the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

You missed an `initialize`. Change:

```
class Checking < Account
  def 
     super
  end

  def balance()
    @balance = principal * (1 + interest_rate / 365) ** 365
  end
end
```

to

```
class Checking < Account
  def initialize
     super
  end

  def balance
    @balance = principal * (1 + interest_rate / 365) ** 365
  end
end
```

And your next issue will be that `Checking#new` (`initialize`) doesn't take parameters, but you call `super` and `Account#new` expects one argument.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what I did wrong I ended up correcting it. Thanks for your guys input it was

```
class Checking < Account
     @@interest_rate = value
  def initialize(method)
     super(parameters)
      @principal = interest_rate
  end

  def balance
    @principal = principal * (1 + interest_rate / 365) ** 365
  end
end
```

that was the answer I was looking for.