# Parent in ruby argument error

Tags: ruby, inheritance, parent

I'm having a hard time initializing the argument B < A 
I keep getting an error on the argument. What do I need to initialize in parameters?

```
class Checking < Account
  def initialize
    super
  end

  def balance
    @balance = principal * (1 + interest_rate / 365) ** 365
  end
end

class Interest_rate
  def interest_rate
    @@interest_rate = 0.003
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `Account`?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your class `Account`. In your edit please be more specific about the error you mention. What was the error message and on what line was the exception raised?

Comment: @AndrewLi I have updated the account

Comment: @SarahKim Your superclass initializer takes an argument so your super call must supply that too

Comment: @CarySwoveland 'initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)

Comment: I don't see how you initialize Checking.

Comment: Interesting. I saw this question coming and answered it [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40572269/2483313) already. Seems like they are working on the same homework.

Comment: @spickermann: ah, isn't it the same user? I totally thought they were. :)

Comment: @spickermann: or this one is a fake account for the same user, created because your answer didn't quite solve the all of user's problems (required parameters) and they didn't want to appear stupid or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

```
def initialize(initial_deposit)
```

You were defining a zero-argument `initialize`, and delegating to a parent one-argument `initialize`.

Comment: Also, `@balance = #{@principal} * (1 + #{@interest_rate} / 365) ** 365` doesn't seem like valid Ruby syntax...

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Amadan's answer:

```
def initialize
    super
end
```

This initializer in Checking class is not only useless, it's harmful. It declares that Checking does not accept any parameters, while it clearly should. Remove this method and it should work fine.

(in absence of defined initializer, one from parent will be used)